# Compare numerical values using different reference rows in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an assignment that asks me to compute whether the score difference in several classes of students is higher than 0.2 based on picking one or more reference students in every classes that bear the reference score.

Here is the example data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
     'class' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     'type' : ['top', 'top', 'low', 'mid', 'mid', 'mid', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low'],
     'score' : [1, .8, .3, .7, .7, .6, .1, .2, .1, .1]})
df
```

The algorithm should contain the following rules

1. Pick the reference student by first giving priority to 'top' and then 'mid' performing students and checking who's closer to the base 0.5 in case of multiple candidates (In the example in 'Class 1' we have two 'top' students but we pick the second with 0.8 which is closer to 0.5 and in 'Class 2' we pick both 'mid' students with 0.6 which is closer to 0.5 than the student with 0.7 and we don't have any 'top' students)
2. Calculate the difference of every non-reference student score with the reference and write 'yes' in case of a difference >0.2 or 'no' in case of a difference <=0.2.

So the final outcome will be

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'student' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
     'class' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     'type' : ['top', 'top', 'low', 'mid', 'mid', 'mid', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low'],
     'score' : [1, .8, .3, .7, .6, .6, .1, .2, .1, .1],
     'outcome' : ['no', 'ref', 'yes', 'no', 'ref', 'ref', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']})
df2
```

I have some basic knowledge of pandas but I think this problem is too complicated for me. Do you have any ideas on how to go about it?

Comment: Have you had a go at applying your experience to step 1 here? There's presumably ways at this stage you might be expected to do it based on what you already know... answers given here may be completely useless to you if done in other ways...

Answer (score 1):

```
def final_output(df):
    # groups class & type
    groups = df2.groupby(['class', 'type'])

    # cl will have key as 'Class' & value as 'reference student score' 
    cl = {}
    for name,group in groups:
        if 'top' in name[1]:
            cl[name[0]] = group['score'].min()
        elif 'mid' in name[1]:
            cl[name[0]] = group['score'].min()

    # Assigning reference student score to their respective class students
    df['refer_score'] = df['class'].apply(lambda x: cl[x])
    # difference being reference student score minus actual score of the student
    df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: abs(x['refer_score'] - x['score']), axis=1)

    df['final_outcome'] = df['diff'].apply(lambda x: 'yes' if x > 0.2 else 'ref' if x == 0.0 else 'no')
    return df

output = final_output(df2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. The process should select the reference with the lowest distance from 0.5 despite giving priority to top, mid etc. so I think that it should be useful to incorporate df['diff_05'] = df.apply(lambda x: abs(x['score'] - 0.5), axis=1) and find the min() afterwards. I will suggest an edit if I get the final code working, but your answer is always welcome.